# Attempt to install Ubuntu with rEFInd for dual boot overwrote Mac OXs main boot record; how do I recover and reconnect?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Installed rEFInd on OSx and had to do so using the recovery partition (due to "rootless" default for later versions of OSx).  I cut the size of my Macintosh HD down and created two unformatted free spaces.  Then booted Ubuntu from a flash drive to begin install.  I did not get the "install Ubuntu alongside OSx" option and used an answer from here to "do something else" and create a SWAP and EXT4 space, then installed Ubuntu into the EXT4 space (it properly ID'd that there was swap space).  All seemed to go well, until I shutdown Ubuntu and then tried do restart the Mac, expecting rEFInd to show me two options.  Nope, Ubuntu boots on power on -- believe this means the master boot record for the disk itself is overwritten.

I can still start OSx by holding the OPTION key down at power up and then selecting the Macintosh HD (the OSx recovery partition is also intact, and will boot).

So, how do I "recover" from this and have the ability to use rEFInd to choose which opsys to boot?

Your reponses and ideas are much appreciated ... thank you.  AMS